# AsyncTask stop on background

Tags: android, background, android-asynctask

i'm building app for listening to acc stream. I m using this library:
https://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/

Especially this player.

```
PlayerCallback clb = new PlayerCallback() { ... };
MultiPlayer aacMp3Player = new MultiPlayer( clb );
aacMp3Player.playAsync( "http://..." ); // URL of MP3 or AAC stream
```

It's playing in AsyncTask, but for some smarphones when you put app to backround playing just stop. 
Only in methond onDestroy i'm stopping AsyncTask, not in onPause or oStop.

Anyone have an idea why player stops?

Comment: too generic, try calling the player from a new thread

Comment: See my answer below. Also, it is not recommended that you do a very long running action in an AsyncTask. Android is currently doing AsyncTask as a "one at a time" model. A long running AsyncTask will block other AsyncTasks from running in the same pool/process. I would suspect that the programming model behind an object with a method called "playAsync" is meant to be called form the UI thread and plays in the background with its own thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Music streaming apps need to have a Service running to avoid being terminated by Android.

On a cheaper device or when memory resources run low, Android will simply terminate processes as soon as they go into the background or when more memory is needed. This likely explains why it only happens on "some smartphones" as you mentioned.  You can also go into the Developer Options on your phone and play with the "Don't Keep Activities" and "Background process limit" settings to simulate the same thing.

You can read more about how Android prioritizes processes and activities for termination when they are not the active app in the foreground [at this link here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle).  You'll read that Services are at higher priority for being kept around than background processes (e.g. Activities that the user exited from, but still have a running thread).

On my music streaming app, when music starts, I start a service (same process as the Activity) and add my app's Main Activity to the Notification area.  When the user stops the music, I stop the service and remove the app from the notification area. You'll likely notice very similar behavior between the [NPR App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.npr.android.news), Spotify, i-heart-radio, and others.

Comment: Thank you.. I will try it! :) So i should put starting player into service?

Comment: You technically don't need to put anything "in the service".  You just need to have a service started before the user leaves the activity for the home screen.  You can expand your service later to offer commands and interface to control your media player. That will open the door for adding a widget that can control your streams from the Android desktop.